# How do I flag a tag for it to be renamed?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags

I want to change [nightmare-b4-christmas](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nightmare-b4-christmas) to [nightmare-before-christmas](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nightmare-before-christmas) because apparently it's [possible to have longer tags now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197889/raising-the-25-chars-limit-for-tags/299490#299490), but I can't find a way to edit this tag name, and I can't find a way to make a tag synonym either

I made the tag so I was expecting to at least be able to suggest an edit to it, but apparently it doesn't work that way

How do I flag this [tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tag) for edit? Or can we get a feature for suggesting edit to a tag?

Comment: resolved already

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to rename a tag, you do what you just did: raise a meta on it, and then a moderator can rename the tag.

Since this tag only has one question, you should probably just remove the tag from the question, save the tag wiki text, add the new tag, and put the tag wiki into the new tag. The old tag will be automatically deleted after a little while.

Comment: Actually, in this case we *shouldn't* save the tag wiki text, because it's plagiarised from Wikipedia. (You're right in general though.)